# Get Image from sdcard using Prefix?

Tags: android

I am using json to get the image from url and successfully stored into sdcard.
I want to get image from sdcard and display into gridview. when I am using below code I can easily get the all image and easily display into grid view.

```
public void getFromSdcard() {
   ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();
   File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/IMG");
   if (file.isDirectory()) {
      listFile = file.listFiles();
      Log.v("Length", "IMG ::" + listFile.length);
      for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
         f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is I don't want to display all the images into grid view, i want to display specific images (using image prefix).

for example i have list of jpg below

```
LR-001.jpg
LR-002.jpg
GR-001.jpg
GR-002.jpg
CF-001.jpg
CF-002.jpg
ER-001.jpg
ER-002.jpg
GBR-001.jpg
GBR-002.jpg
GPT-001.jpg
GPT-002.jpg
NCK-001.jpg
NCK-002.jpg
```

how to get image of **GR prefix?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the filename starts with "GR" for instance:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
        String fileName = listFile[i].getName();
        if (fileName.startsWith("GR"))
              f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

the same with the for-each

```
   for (File file : listFile) {
        String fileName = file.getName();
        if (fileName.startsWith("GR"))
              f.add(file);
   }
```

to get a random entry from your ArrayList you can use the class Random

```
private Random randomGenerator; 

randomGenerator = new Random();
int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(f.size());
File file = f.get(index);
```

`nexInt` returns a number between `0` and `f.size() - 1`

Comment: a little more help needed if u never mind to help. if i have a several image of prefix **GR** like GR-001, GR-002, GR-003. How can i display a random image on single `image view` in GridView

Comment: i am not able to implement random function bt no problem i will ask another question for it, really thanks for help Sir

Answer (score 0):

You could check your filenames for the starting letters "GR"

Following Code should work

```
List<File> f = new ArrayList<File>();
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/IMG");
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    listFile = file.listFiles();
    Log.v("Length", "IMG ::" + listFile.length);
    for (File file : listFile) {
        if(file.getName().startsWith("GR"){
           f.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FilenameFilter:

```
f = file.list(new FilenameFilter(){
  @Override
  public boolean accept(File dir, String filename){
    if (filename.startsWith("GR")) return true;
    return false;
  }
});
```